# While during the Upgrade, some Errors occured, is it Problematic?

Tags: 12.04, xorg, console, x11

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [My system is totally messed up. What is the best course of action?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/126724/my-system-is-totally-messed-up-what-is-the-best-course-of-action)

Errors on these -

x11-apps,
xorg, 
ubuntu-desktop,
bash-completion,
console-setup, 
ubuntu-minimal

Are They Important any way? ( Yes, I know Ubuntu-Desktop has to be important, but what's with the other?  )

Comment: Yes... those are pretty important. `ubuntu-desktop` the least important, actually. Have you rebooted...? If not I **STRONGLY SUGGEST** you defer rebooting until you get an answer

Comment: Could you list the exact error if possible. Also `sudo apt-get install -f`

Comment: You mean I should reinstall Ubuntu?

Comment: bash-completion: Limit for MaxReports reached

Comment: And some md5hash Inpout/Output Error...

Comment: I forgot to answer... unfortunately, I rebooted!

Comment: Do you have any graphical interface? If so, did you get the output to `sudo apt-get install -f`?

Comment: It's German, so I listed the Two most important outputs..

Comment: But it's OK also. Now I did the Reinstall and everything seems Good.